# Php / json_encode NULL issues

Tags: php, sql-server, json

Good morning,

I have already read the other posts that have similar issues, but nothing is resolving the issue, but bear in mind I am new to the world of PHP and Json. But I am trying to convert a mssql query into json format so that I can then later pass this through google's visualisation api. The query and encoding seems to be working but the encode returns NULL.

I have checked the normal gotcha's of making sure its utf8 encoded and that I have used a version of PHP that has the encode (using php 5.3.19).

Can any one help me with getting the encode to work.

PHP CODE:

```
    <?php
// connection details known to be working fine

if( $conn ) {
echo "Connection established.<br><br>";
}else{
echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM tblMetalPrice";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) );


$arr = array($result);
$encodedarray = array_map(utf8_encode, $arr);

echo json_encode($encodedarray);

sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>
```

When I run this code on the server it comes back with:

Connection established.

[null]

Has anyone got any ideas of getting this to work?

Thanks

Kris

Comment: Check this link for db connection in php : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: are you sure, you are getting data in $encodedarray ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I resolved this was:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblMetalPrice";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) )

{

$encodedarray = array_map(utf8_encode, $row);

echo json_encode($encodedarray);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblMetalPrice";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);
while( $row[] = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ); // Fetch and stor in array


$arr = array($row); // make parent array
$encodedarray = array_map(utf8_encode, $arr);

echo json_encode($encodedarray);
```

You have passed $result which is wrong. $row contain the result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it didn't work 100% but did give me the answer.

Comment: It works fine now see my posted answer :) thanks thou you pointed me in the right direction.